# What does XI8 mean in a SQL query? (Teradata/Big Query)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, teradata

At work I saw I saw a SQL query in Teradata that had the following:

```
CASE WHEN (sp_ce / ‘0000001000000000’XI8) MOD 2 = 1 THEN ‘Y’ ELSE ‘N’ END AS res_p
```

What is the meaning of `XI8`? What is it doing to the number string?

Also when I tried to run this in Big Query it’s not supported, it errors out with

> Syntax error: Unexpected identifier \XI8\

How would I write that case statement in big query?

Using MOD on big query without the numbers as a string and without the XI8 yields different results.

Thank you

Comment: It's effectively casting that hexadecimal string as bigint.  Try just running `select '0000001000000000'XI8`

Comment: BigQuery supports hex integer literals, should be `0x0000001000000000`